# grep between two lines with specified string

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep

I have this simple plat file (file.txt)

```
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
test1
def
ijk
xyz
test2
kfo
```

I need all lines between test1 and test2 in two forms, the firte one create two new files like

**newfile1.txt :**

```
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
```

**newfile2.txt**

```
test1
def
ijk
xyz
test2
```

and the second form create only one new file like :

**newfile.txt**

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2
test1abccvbbnmtest2
```

Do you have any propositions?

For the second form. I used this

```
sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But it give me a result like

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2test1abccvbbnmtest2
```

I need a return line like :

```
test1abccvbbnmtest2
test1abccvbbnmtest2
```

Comment: @roaima I will check this

Comment: This answer might also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022994/2026975

Answer (score 1):

An awk oneliner for the first case:

```
awk '/^test1/{file++; on=1} on{print >("newfile" file ".txt")} /^test2/{on=0}' file.txt
```

which says:

- If `test1` found, increment file number and start output (i.e. turn `on`)
- If turned on, print line to the file name "newfileFILE.txt", where FILE is the file number.
- If `test2` is found, end output (i.e. turn off)

Then, you can convert the two files to `newfile.txt` with the shell oneliner:

```
for file in newfile?.txt; do tr -d '\n' <$file; echo; done > newfile.txt
```

which says, foreach file, remove all linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

For your second form:

```
sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' file.txt | xargs > newfile.txt ; sed 's/test2/&\n/g' newfile.txt | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

- sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' file.txt --> capture text between test1 and test2
- xargs > newfile.txt --> turn text into "row" effectively speaking, altho purpose of xargs perhaps is different.
- sed 's/test2/&\n/g' newfile.txt --> add newline after "test2" pattern
- sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' --> delete spaces at start of each line.